# Search a varchar in a huge table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, ip, varchar

I have a table with 5 million rows +, and I have a `varchar(50)` field to save IPs.

When I run this query, it takes a lot of resources and time:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip = 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx' LIMIT 1
```

What can I do to improve this process?

Comment: Stop running that query.

Comment: do you have any indexes? and don't SELECT *.. SELECT specific fields

Comment: If you can modify the table schema, change the IP column to UNSIGNED INT and then INET_ATON to convert your dotted IPs into 4-byte UNSIGNED INT IPs. Should be way faster than string comparisons. An index on that column would help, too.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

Comment: convert the `ip` string to `long` with `ip2long` function. store this value in the database. and to retrieve the `string` use `long2ip` function.

Answer (score 2):

You need an index on the `ip` column:

```
create index idx_table_ip on table(ip)
```

Then your query should run quickly, assuming that you do not have too many duplicates.

Let me clarify that last statement.  Duplicates will not affect the run-time of this particularly query.  However, when using `limit` you should have an `order by`, so that the results are stable (using the query twice will return the same rows).  In that case, you should include the `order by` column(s) in the index (if possible).  If not, the number of matches will affect performance.

Comment: Thanks! but now I have another issue. When I join 2 tables (by indexed int) with ip column in both `varchar(50)`, and I use `where t1.ip = '..' OR t2.ip = '..'` - It takes a lot of time

Comment: @ArielAharonson . . . You should ask questions as questions and not in comments.  Ask another question, include the query of interest, and the table layouts.